# slow ssh login and logout at "shell request accepted on channel"

Tags: ssh

I have a slow ssh login issue, the server is fast (via wget) but it took 15s to pop a shell.

So I launch ssh with -vv option, I found it stuck at pty request:

```
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0  <-- stuck for 15s
```

At first I suspect it was the bash profile, but adding a `-x` to /etc/profile does not help, nothing was printed on the console. But if I press ^C, lots of output is printed on the console.

And when I exit the shell, it also stuck for ~10s, then printed the following lines:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 8 efd 10 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 9 efd 10 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to xxxx closed.
Transferred: sent 3296, received 2720 bytes, in 78.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 42.0, received 34.7
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Does anyone know how to debug this issue? I have totally no idea now.

Comment: Is it a DNS timeout ?

Comment: @StefanSkoglund UseDNS is set to no already

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using valid nameservers or either put `UseDNS no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.